# Linux unable to find and execute script, despite being in the correct directory

Tags: linux, scripting

I have a basic start script for an application that I am trying to run.  However, every time I execute it:

```
./start.sh
```

It fails with this error:

```
-ksh: ./start.sh: not found [No such file or directory]
```

This is despite the fact that I am in the same directory as the script, and I have permissions to run it.  To further test, I made a simple test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo test
```

Executing this with `./test.sh` produces `test`.

Comment: What is the first line of the script that doesn't work, and did you create it on your Linux system or on a Windows/Mac machine? Please [edit] your question to answer this - don't reply here as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing - the script was written on a Windows machine with Intellij, and so was using the Windows line separators instead of Linux.  Once I fixed that, the script ran like it was supposed to.

I'm sorry if I wasted anyone's time.